# Trouble subscribing to ActiveMQ Artemis with Stomp. Queue already exists

Tags: python, stomp, activemq-artemis

What am I doing wrong here? I'm trying to use Stomp to test some things with Artemis 2.13.0, but when I uses either the command line utility of a Python script, I can't subscribe to a queue, even after I use the utility to publish a message to an address.

Also, if I give it a new queue name, it creates it, but then doesn't pull messages I publish to it. This is confusing. My actual Java app behaves nothing like this -- it's using JMS

I'm connection like this with the utility:

```
stomp -H 192.168.56.105 -P 61616 -U user -W password
> subscribe test3.topic::test.A.queue
```

Which give me this error:

```
Subscribing to 'test3.topic::test.A.queue' with acknowledge set to 'auto', id set to '1'
>
AMQ229019: Queue test.A.queue already exists on address test3.topic
```

Which makes me think Stomp is trying to create the queue when it subscribes, but I don't see how to manage this in the documentation. http://jasonrbriggs.github.io/stomp.py/api.html

I also have a Python script giving me the same issue.

```
import os
import time
import stomp

def connect_and_subscribe(conn):
    conn.connect('user', 'password', wait=True)
    conn.subscribe(destination='test3.topic::test.A.queue', id=1, ack='auto')

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def __init__(self, conn):
        self.conn = conn

    def on_error(self, headers, message):
        print('received an error "%s"' % message)

    def on_message(self, headers, message):
        print('received a message "%s"' % message)
        """for x in range(10):
            print(x)
            time.sleep(1)
        print('processed message')"""

    def on_disconnected(self):
        print('disconnected')
        connect_and_subscribe(self.conn)

conn = stomp.Connection([('192.168.56.105', 61616)], heartbeats=(4000, 4000))
conn.set_listener('', MyListener(conn))
connect_and_subscribe(conn)
time.sleep(1000)
conn.disconnect()
```

Comment: How come you're using the fully-qualified-queue-name (FQQN)? Normal use-cases don't require this. Also, what version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: I've tried only use the queue name as well. I expected the queues to be created by the subscribe and then disappear after disconnecting, and that FQQNs are best for this.

Comment: There are distinct differences between how multicast (aka pub-sub or topic) and anycast (aka point-to-point or queue) semantics work. What exact behavior are you looking for? Also, what version of ActiveMQ Artemis are you using?

Comment: Artemis 2.13.0  Multicast. I'm publishing to an address with the intention of creating queues to subscribe to, while the subscribers are connected.

Comment: If you're using multicast and you want your clients to receive the messages published to an address then why not just subscribe to the multicast address (i.e. topic) rather than the FQQN? That's what is normally done for this use-case.

Comment: What about if I want to filters, so clients can subscribe to messages based on header values? I guess I didn't realize you could subscribe directly to an address.

Comment: You'd use the `selector` header in your `SUBSCRIBE` frame for that similar to what you'd use for a JMS client. You should create a new question if you want more details on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you try the [latest release of ActiveMQ Artemis](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/). Since 2.13.0 was released a year ago a handful of STOMP related issues have been fixed specifically [ARTEMIS-2817](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2817) which looks like your use-case.

It's not clear to me *why* you're using the fully-qualified-queue-name (FQQN) so I'm inclined to think this is not the right approach, but regardless the issue you're hitting should be fixed in later versions. If you want multiple consumers to *share* the messages on a single subscription then using FQQN would be a good option there.

Also, if you want to use the `topic/` or `queue/` prefix to control routing semantics from the broker then you should set the `anycastPrefix` and `multicastPrefix` appropriately as described in [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/stomp.html#configuring-routing-semantics-from-the-broker-side).

---

This may be coincidence but [ARTEMIS-2817](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-2817) was originally reported by "BENJAMIN Lee WARRICK" which is surprisingly similar to "BenW" (i.e. your name).

Comment: So if I have multiple subscribers that need to share the messages, I should subscribe to the topic (address)? I upgraded to 2.17. Stomp works better now, but when I subscribe to test.topic, I get an error that says queue: test.topic does not exist. If I try topic/test.topic, an new topic appear in Artemis "topic/test.topic". I'm getting more confused.

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. As far as the "queue: test.topic does not exist" issue goes you'd probably need to create a new question for that so you can flesh out all the details. Hope that helps!